# How to display information by determining the date range

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want input date for show Data only range 
Here is my code:

```vb
Dim sqls As String

Dim Sta As Date

Dim En As Date

Sta = InputBox("Please enter the start date, in the YYYY-MM-DD format")

En = InputBox("Please enter the End date, in the YYYY-MM-DD format")

'SQL '

sqls = "SELECT TABLE A.ID,TABLE A.Name,Table A.DatePayment,TABLE B.Des,TABLE D.Comcode,TABLE D.Comdes,TABLE C.Type,TABLE C.TypeDes 

FROM TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B ON TABLE A.ID = TABLE B.ID

sqls = sqls & " WHERE Table A.DatePayment BETWEEN" & Sta & " AND " & En

Set rs = conn.Execute(sqls)
```

I get this error:

> Error :An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where
>   a condition is expected, near ‘BETWEEN'

Comment: Not wishing to promote SQL injection hacking (it seems unlikely this is an enterprise system. If it is, change your approach) but, try `sqls = sqls & " WHERE Table A.DatePayment BETWEEN #" & Sta & "# AND #" & En & "#"` if youre using ms access. If not, let us know what database you're using

Comment: I Use SQL Server ,Code USe VBA

Comment: Spaces in `"SELECT TABLE A.ID,T ..` make it totally wrong syntactically. Correct it before any other bug hunting.

Comment: I thing issue in                                                                                                 
Dim Sta As Date
Dim En As Date      Because  sql = String  when use sql WHERE will Error please Help me How To  Convert String to Date

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if "TABLE A" and "TABLE B" are the actual table names (or the actual names contain spaces) you have to enclose the name in a [] pair. Second, you have to enclose the date value in a pair of single quotes. Third, you specify some tables C and D in the SELECT section but not in the FROM section. All these result in SQL syntax errors and need to be fixed.

Comment: Code Error after have WHERE  if have SELECT ,FROM Only Can Run,I Thing issue in WHERE but i must  use codition for show Data Date range.Because Data So Big and slow

Comment: You need to fix the 2nd issue I mentioned above. You should try: sqls = sqls & " WHERE Table A.DatePayment BETWEEN '" & Sta & "' AND '" & En & "'". Similar to Caius Jard's answer, but with single quotes instead of hashes.